# Logistics regression in R plotting Bootstrap using Titanic Dataset

Tags: r, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression, statistics-bootstrap

I am working on an exercise for a statistics online course. I need to create a logistic regression in R using the titanic dataset. Therefore I want to apply the bootstrap method to create and plot  95% confidence intervals for the prediction of the logistic regression.

When I run the bootstrap command and want to plot it, I get the error: "All values of t* are equal to 0.0159971772980342". Also, I get a bias and standard error of 0, which cannot be true. I guess there is an error in setting up the bootstrap command, but I unfortunately cannot find it. What can I try?

My Code:

```
library(boot)

set.seed(50000)

logit_test <- function(data, indices) {  
  dt <- data[indices,]  
  fit <- glm(Clean_data$Survived ~ Fare, data = Clean_data, family = "binomial")  
  return(coef(fit))  
}
boot_strap <- boot(  
  data = Clean_data, 
  statistic = logit_test, 
  R = 100)

boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap,  
        type = c("basic"))


#Now we look at the results and plot them

boot_strap

plot(boot_strap, index=2)
```

My Output:

```
> library(boot)
> 
> set.seed(50000)
> 
> logit_test <- function(data, indices) {  
+   dt <- data[indices,]  
+   fit <- glm(Clean_data$Survived ~ Fare, data = Clean_data, family = "binomial")  
+   return(coef(fit))  
+ }
> boot_strap <- boot(  
+   data = Clean_data, 
+   statistic = logit_test, 
+   R = 100)
> 
> boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap,  
+         type = c("basic"))
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 100 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot_strap, type = c("basic"))

Intervals : 
Level      Basic         
95%   (-0.8968, -0.8968 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some basic intervals may be unstable
> boot_strap

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = Clean_data, statistic = logit_test, R = 100)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original  bias    std. error
t1* -0.89682819       0           0
t2*  0.01599718       0           0
> plot(boot_strap, index=2)
[1] "All values of t* are equal to  0.0159971772980342"
```

Comment: I answered your question below, but in the future, please post the code itself and not a picture of the code - it will make it easier for us to help.

Comment: I disagree a little with Dave - the substance of their comment is right, but I think the question is off-topic until the code is repaired. Code/logs trapped in images don't work with clipboards, screen-readers, or search-engine robots.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're bootstrap function isn't using the bootstrapped data to fit the model. You have this function:

```
logit_test <- function(data, indices){
  dt <- data[indices, ]
  fit <- glm(Clean_Travelers$Survived ~ FARE, data=Clean_Travelers, 
             family=binomial)
  return(coef(fit))
}
```

Note that there are a couple of problems, one is that you should be using `dt` in the `data=` argument, but you should also not be using `Clean_Travelers$Survived` as the dependent variable, it should just be `Survived` because you want to ensure that you're taking that variable not from the original data, but from the bootstrapped data.  Something like this for your bootstrap function should work:

```
logit_test <- function(data, indices){
  dt <- data[indices, ]
  fit <- glm(Survived ~ FARE, data=dt, family=binomial)
  return(coef(fit))
}
```